# NodeJS writing binary data to file without overwriting

Tags: node.js

I am currently trying to write a binary file using NodeJS.

I have now the issue that I have no clue how to insert data between two bytes without overwriting the following bytes.

## Example

Given: 
`04 42 55 43 48 04`

I know want to insert `55` between `43` and `48`.

Expected result: `04 42 55 43 55 48 04`

Actual result: `04 42 55 43 55 04`

## Code

I am using the following code to write to my file:

```
fs.write(fd, 0x55, 4, (err) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    fs.close(fd);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find any solution so I wrote it my self

```
function insert_data(fd, data, position, cb) {
    // ensure data i Buffer
    if (!Buffer.isBuffer(data)) {
        data = Buffer.from(data);
    }
    // get file size
    fs.fstat(fd, (err, stat) => {
        if (err) {
            return cb(err);
        }
        // calculate size for following bytes in file and allocate
        const buffer_size = stat.size > position ? stat.size - position : 0;
        const buffer = Buffer.alloc(buffer_size);
        // read bytes to by written after inserted data
        fs.read(fd, buffer, 0, buffer_size, position, (err, bytesRead, buffer) => {
            if (err) {
                return cb(err);
            }
            // concatenate new buffer containing data to be inserted and remaining bytes 
            const new_buffer = Buffer.concat([
                data,
                buffer
            ], data.length + buffer_size);
            // write new buffer starting from given position
            fs.write(fd, new_buffer, 0, new_buffer.length, position, (err) => {
                if (err) {
                    return cb(err);
                }
                fs.close(fd, cb);
            });
        });
    });
}

fs.open("test.bin", "r+", (err, fd) => {
    insert_data(fd, [0x55], 4, console.dir);
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much :) Was thinking about that approach as well but didn't want to make it more complicated than needed.